# Oracle deadlock on non-foreign key column

Tags: oracle, deadlock

1. We have a table **A** which has a column *X* in Oracle database.
2. *X* column is a numeric column and it is **NOT** a foreign key to any table.
3. Our application does refresh of the data (delete old
   data, get new data, query for the *max value of column X*, then
   inserts data in table A).
4. Updating description: We see the deadlock in the application logs. To be
   precise `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource.`
5. Just so we know this application uses spring and hibernate. The query is in HQL.

Has anyone encountered this situation before? Given that column *X* does not have any foreign key constraints, we are really stumped as to why deadlock should appear on that column.

Thanks for your help and inputs.

Comment: Is this *really* a deadlock?  If so, are you getting ORA-00060 or ORA-04020?  If it's an ORA-00060, then please lookup the trace file that was generated, and post the deadlock graph, the statement that encountered the deadlock, and the other statement(s) involved in the deadlock, from the trace file.  This is critical information in interpreting the deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

As of 4: what do you mean "it seems like Oracle is detecting a deadlock"? There is, or is NOT a deadlock.

Did you query V$LOCKED_OBJECT? Such a query might help:

```
select
  o.owner,
  o.object_name,
  o.object_type
from
  v$locked_object l ,
  v$session s,
  dba_objects o
where l.object_id = o.object_id
  and s.sid = l.session_id;
```

Does it return anything?

Furthermore, what makes you think that there is a deadlock? Is there any error there? If so, which one?

Finally, what happens if you create index on the X column of the A table?

Comment: I should have been more forceful in the language. We see the deadlock in the application logs. To be precise

Comment: I should have been more forceful in the language. We see the deadlock in the application logs. To be precise `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource`. They have not tried adding Index.